# c++ no operator matches even when operator is defined

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement custom reference in C++. What I want to achieve is to have reference, which does not need to be set at creation. It looks like this

```
template<typename T>
class myreference
{
    public:
        myreference() : data(), isset(false) { }
        explicit myreference(const T& _data) : data(&_data), isset(true) { }
        myreference<T>& operator=(T& t)
        {
            if (!isset)
            {
                isset= true;
                data = &t;
            }
            else
                *data = t;
            return *this;
        }

        operator T() const { return *data; }
        operator T&() { return *data; }
    private:
        T* data;
        bool isset;
};
```

It works fine. I can do this, except for last statement.

```
myreference<int> myref;
int data = 7, test = 3;
myref = data; // reference is set
myref = test; // data is now 3
int& i = myref;
i = 4; // data is now 4
cout << myref; // implicit int conversion
myref = 42; // error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int'
```

Full error

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          d:\...\main.cpp(33): could be 'myreference<int> &myreference<int>::operator =(const myreference<int> &)'
1>          d:\...\main.cpp(16): or       'myreference<int> &myreference<int>::operator =(T &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list 'myreference<int>, int'
```

I was searching through the web and found similar errors (with **different** operators) and the result was to put the operator outside of its class, but that is not possible for `operator=` for some (I believe good) reason. My question is, what is the compiler complaining about? Argument list is `myreference<int>, int` and I have operator defined for `T`s which, in this case, is `int`.

Comment: did you try to add a `const` to the operator=? `myreference<T>& operator=(T const & t)`

Comment: @Hans `operator=` can't be const since it's modifying contents of an object, `T&` as parameter of `operator=` can't be const either, because I am assigning it to non const variable (and thus having an option to modify it).

Comment: The parameter can well be const even if you assign it in `*data=t;`. In that line, you modify *data, not t, thus t may be const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myreference<T>& operator=(T& t)
myref = 42;
```

non-const reference can't be bound to a temporary. You can change it to take parameter by const reference.

```
myreference<T>& operator=(const T& t)
```

Also, make changes in your code to make this work.

```
data = &t;                         <<< Replace this
data = const_cast<T*>(&t);         <<< with this.
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realized I can't pass literal to non-const reference. I'll accept your answer in 3mins (WTF stackexchange rules)

Comment: /pedantic: rvalue-reference can too.

Comment: Sir ravi, may I ask why const_cast is required?

Comment: `data = const_cast<T*>(&t);` may make it compile, but does not mean you shoukd type that.  @zereges assigning 42 here points out that your `myreference` is pretty fundamantally flawed: reference rebinding and assignment are not the same operation.

Answer (score 1):

You instantiated an object of type `myreference<int>`

```
myreference<int> myref;
```

So the assignment operator is specialized for parameter type `int &`. However you are trying to assogn a temporary object that may be bound to a constant reference. So the assignment operator has to be specialized for parameter type `const int &`.

Thus you need to define another object of type `myreference<const int>` that the code would be at least compiled. For example

```
myreference<const int> myref1;

myref1 = 42;
```

However in any case the code will have undefined behaviour because the temporary object will be deleted after the executing this assignment statement and data member data will have invalid value.

Usually such claases suppress using temporary objects that to avoid the undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is bigger than the compiler error.  The compiler error is telling you that you have a fundamental design error.

Your reference `=` both acts as a reference rebinder (changes what an empty reference is attached to) and an assignment (chanhes the value of the thing attached to).  These are fundamantally different operations.

One requires a long-term value you can modify later (rebind), and the other requres a value you can read from (assignment).

However with one function, the parameter passed has to be either -- and those types do not match.  A readable from value is a `T const&`.  A bindable value is a `T&`.

If you change the type to `T const&` the rebind `data = &t` fails, as it should.  If you pass a temporary, like `42`, to your `=`, a rebind attaches to it, and becomes invalid at the end of the calling line.  Similarly if you assign `int const foo = 3;` to it.

You can 'fix' this with a `const_cast`, but that just throws the type checking out the window: it hides the undefined behaviour instead of giving you a diagnosis.

The `T&` parameter, on the other hand, cannot bind to a `42` temporary, nor can it bind to a constant `const int foo = 3`.  Which is great in the rebind case, but makes assignment sort of useless.

If you have two operations, `=(T const &)` and `.rebind(T&)`, your problem goes away.  As a side effect, `=` when not set is indefined behaviour.  But that was basically true before.

Your reference is probably better called a 'pointer' at this point.

Comment: I will never change what my reference points to, that's why I don't have rebind method. Let's call it "pointer, that does not need to be dereferenced in order to get its value".

Comment: @zereges `myreference() : data(), isset(false) { }` -- not bound to anything.  Then assign, is bound.  You changed what it was bound to, from nothing to something.  The type makes no guarantees about being bound, nor what `=` does: it is a worse type (safety wise) than a raw pointer.  Operators should not, based on runtime state, change the type of data they demand, as a general rule.

Answer (score 0):

Since assignment operator is expecting  variable (in this case an integer) you are not allowed to pass it some value(42).
So use an integer like

```
int x=42;
myref=x;
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Why is it expecting variable? I want it to accept number.

Comment: 42 is an int and cannot be used as int&

Comment: basically it is expecting a reference (an int reference) so you cant use number there directly. store it in variable and pass it over